# Excel Schedule VBA to run at certain time

Tags: vba, excel, timer

have a VBA code that saved some cells to a new row every 5 seconds. I'd like to run this task from 7am to 8pm everyday. Then delete cells after 10pm so I can start fresh next day (delete range B2:C10000). Appreciate your help. Below is my current macro:

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date

Sub ValueStore()
    Dim RowNo As Long
    RowNo = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets("Data").Cells(RowNo, 2) = Sheets("GetData").Cells(2, 2).Value2
    Sheets("Data").Cells(RowNo, 3) = Sheets("GetData").Cells(2, 5).Value2    
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
Sub StartTimer()

    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Use an If statement to check the current time?

Comment: This looks like a good task for Windows Service Application - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a looping sub to run different tasks:

```
If hasRun = False Then
    Sheets("GetData").Range("H1").Value = "Running"
    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True

    Application.OnTime TimeValue(Sheets("GetData").Range("O1").Text), "StartTimer"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(Sheets("GetData").Range("O2").Text), "StopTimer"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(Sheets("GetData").Range("O3").Text), "DeleteData"
    hasRun = True
End If
```

End Sub